# NGINX regular extension in uri

Tags: regex, nginx, location, uri

I have to mask just part of URI in NGINX location.

For example

I have a rule which I want to apply to any locations

```
location /photos/friends/city-somestreet-***/
#proxy_cache start
        set of rules...
...

location /photos/dudes/city-cafe-***/
#proxy_cache start
        set of rules
...
```

It can be anything instead stars (* * *)

/photos/friends/city-somestreet-2013/ -fits

/photos/dudes/city-cafe-arrrrh/ - fits too

But

/photos/friends/TOWN-somestreet-2013/ - doesn't fit

/photos/dudes/SOMEPLACE/city-cafe-2011/ - doesn't fit

but cant find any examples.

Is it possible at all? 
What rule or directive should I use?

I know that it will be easier to separate location path like

```
 /photos/friends/city/somestreet/***/
```

but, if it possible to realize my plan?

Comment: just a note, your rules looks weird, you should use [proxy_cache_methods](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cache_methods).

Comment: Sorry but this is just for example, it is not real rule. I will fix it

Comment: why can't the rules be `location /photos/friends` and then handle every thing in your application

Comment: Becauce there could be location like     `location /photos/friends/garbage/bla-bla-bla` or  `location /photos/friends/TOWN-somestreet-bla-bla` I dont want to apply rules for that directory.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy

```
location ~ "^/photos/friends/city-somestreet-(\w+\/)"
#proxy_cache start
    set of rules...
```

or (\d+/) if we are going to use digits.